# VBA optimization worksheet data transfer

Tags: excel, vba

My code works but it takes over 3 hours to execute on 36000 lines on sheet 1 and 10000 on sheet 2. I would like another way to change two cells data from another sheet where two cells are equal.

```
Sub test_function()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    line_count1 = ws1.Range("A1").End(xlDown).row
    line_count2 = ws2.Range("A1").End(xlDown).row

    For i = 2 To line_count1
        For j = 2 To line_count2

        If CStr(ws1.Range("d" & i).Value) = CStr(ws2.Range("c" & j).Value) And CStr(ws1.Range("f" & i).Value) = CStr(ws2.Range("e" & j).Value) Then
            ws1.Range("q" & i).Value = ws2.Range("a" & j).Value
            ws1.Range("r" & i).Value = ws2.Range("b" & j).Value
        End If

        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Learn to dump entire ranges into 2D variant arrays, and then 2D variant arrays into a `Range`, and iterate and query arrays instead of ranges; look into how `Application.ScreenUpdating` and `Application.Calculation` and `Application.EnableEvents` flags can impact your code's execution time (although, if you're working with arrays it won't be of much use, but they're good to know about regardless).

Comment: This question is more appropriate for Code Review

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub test_function()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    line_count1 = ws1.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    line_count2 = ws2.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    Dim r2() As Variant
    Dim r1() As Variant

    ' get all data from both ranges
    r2 = ws2.Range("a2:e" & line_count2)
    r1 = ws1.Range("d2:r" & line_count1)

    For i = 2 To line_count1
        For j = 2 To line_count2

        If CStr(r1(1, i)) = CStr(r2(3, j)) And CStr(r1(3, i)) = CStr(r2(5, j)) Then
            r1(13, i) = r2(1, j)
            r1(14, i) = r2(2, j)
        End If

        Next j
    Next i

    'paste the changed range1 back
    ws1.Range("d2:r" & line_count1) = r1
End Sub
```

This shows how to do the same thing as your original code, but using range-array copying instead of browsing individual cells.  This is not the most efficient way possible (because it is still copying a lot of unnecessary cells), but it should be much faster.

---

UPDATE:

OK, now *this* version is probably about a fast as possible for this task:

```
Sub Fast_test_function()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    line_count1 = ws1.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    line_count2 = ws2.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    ' copy each needed column into an array
    Dim d1(), f1(), q1(), r1(), c2(), e2(), a2(), b2()
    d1 = ws1.Range("d1:d" & line_count1)
    f1 = ws1.Range("f1:f" & line_count1)
    q1 = ws1.Range("q1:q" & line_count1)
    r1 = ws1.Range("r1:r" & line_count1)

    c2 = ws2.Range("c1:c" & line_count2)
    e2 = ws2.Range("e1:e" & line_count2)
    a2 = ws2.Range("a1:a" & line_count2)
    b2 = ws2.Range("b1:b" & line_count2)

    ' load the lookup collections
    Dim sKey As String, i As Long, j As Long, str As String
    Dim colA2 As New Collection, colB2 As New Collection

    On Error Resume Next    ' ignore duplicate key errors
    For j = 2 To line_count2
        sKey = CStr(c2(j)) & "~" & CStr(e2(j))
        colA2.Add CStr(a2(j)), sKey
        colB2.Add CStr(b2(j)), sKey
    Next j

    ' set the output array values
    For i = 2 To line_count1
        sKey = CStr(d1(i)) & "~" & CStr(f1(i))
        On Error Resume Next    ' suppress Missing Key errors
        str = colA2(sKey)
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            q1(i) = str
            str = colB2(sKey)
            r1(i) = str
        End If
    Next i
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' copy the output arrays back to the output ranges
    ws1.Range("q1:q" & line_count1) = q1
    ws1.Range("r1:r" & line_count1) = r1
End Sub
```

Though a version that uses Dictionaries instead of Collections might be slightly faster.

Answer (score 0):

You are are making 360,000 individual comparisons, which is going to be slow.

It seems you are looking for the last time the value in ws1 col D appears in ws1 col C, and then copying something from ws2 to ws1.

At least 26,000 of the rows in ws1 won't find an answer, and there will be ways of finding if a row is one of them without having to cycle through 10,000 comparisons.

As a first step, rather that make the code grab the value in ws1 D? 10,000 times, place it in a variable then compare that variable to ws2

Also worth holding min and max values from ws2 col C in variables and using them to shortcut the screening.

Answer (score 0):

Idea is to pre-sort both of the lists first and then search in the sorted list is much faster, as you do not have to start over and you can stop as soon as you hit value equal or greater than what you are searching for.

Following code works on the data in the 4 Columns - `A, B, C, D` and it looks for the matches within `A` and `B` columns on `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` and then copies values from `Sheet2` columns `C` and `D` into `Sheet1` columns `E` and `F`. Adjust this to whatever columns you will be using. For 36000 rows on `Sheet1` and 10000 rows on `Sheet2` total time was less then 5 seconds.

The Code:

```
Sub test_function()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    ws1.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ws1.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "A2:A36000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    ws1.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "B2:B36000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ws1.Sort
        .SetRange Range("A2:D36000")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    ws2.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ws2.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "A2:A36000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    ws2.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "B2:B36000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ws2.Sort
        .SetRange Range("A2:D36000")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    i = 2
    j = 2
    Do While ws1.Cells(i, "A") <> ""
        Do While ws2.Cells(j, "A") <> "" And ws2.Cells(j, "A") < ws1.Cells(i, "A")
            j = j + 1
        Loop
        If ws2.Cells(j, "A") = ws1.Cells(i, "A") And ws2.Cells(j, "B") = ws1.Cells(i, "B") Then
            ws1.Cells(i, "E") = ws2.Cells(j, "C")
            ws1.Cells(i, "F") = ws2.Cells(j, "D")
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

This can be optimized to handle properly if your values in first column hold multiple duplicate values.